# Calculated column suddenly generates error, "The setting you entered isn't valid for this property."

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, calculated-columns

Around mid-February, 2021, in Microsoft Access, opening tables to linked SharePoint lists with calculated columns started suddenly generating the error, "The setting you entered isn't valid for this property".  A simple example to reproduce the error would be a SharePoint list with separate First Name and Last Name columns and a SharePoint calculated column with the formula =[Last Name]&" "&[First Name].  This previously worked for years.  After acknowledging the error in Access, the table opens, and all the columns display as expected.  Queries appear unaffected, but the error is still disconcerting.  I have tried refreshing, re-linking, repair/compact, disk cleanup, reboot, recreate a copy of everything, etc. but the error persists.  Has anybody else started experiencing the same error, and have you discovered the source and any resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a solution.  In Access, under File | Options | Current Database | Caching Web Service and SharePoint tables | un-checking Use the cache format that is compatible with Microsoft Access 2010 and later eliminated the error.  Not sure why that suddenly mattered, but toggling the setting effectively toggles the error on/off.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old thread, I face the same problem.
For some reasons, a concatenated field is not transferred correctly

You will find an empty expression in your linked table definition. In my case, this causes the error. If I take a simple reference to one of the fields, if works like a charm...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).